# Right to Left support for TextView in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, right-to-left, persian

I'm developing an application for Android in Persian. I fetch data from SQLite database and display them, using TextView. How can I display the text (that contains multiple lines ) from right to left?

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you want to display from Right to Left?

Answer (score 1):

If the ROM supports right-to-left, which is most likely the case if you bought your mobile in the middle east, then you can set the gravity to right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right, but I want to sell app, all over the world, not limited to middle east. I need a general solution.

Comment: If the problem is just in the mirroring, then as Pyrodante said, you can just mirror the string before you set it to the TextView, but if there is a problem in the glyphs mapping as in the Arabic language, then there is no general solution, since this require modifications in the android ROM itself.

Answer (score 0):

If Android does not support this natively (I'm not sure), you could create a string reverser that swaps the nth char with the string.length() - nth character until you have a reflected string, and then post that right justified.

Answer (score 0):

If the ROM doesn't support right-to-left rendering, you could possibly use the [`java.text.Bidi`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html) class that implements the Unicode Bidi Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since it wasn't asked very good it was not answered.
@Farina, I believe the answer you are looking for is here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

In essence: By creating a layout-ar folder right next to your layout folder and placing an rtl oriented layout file in it you can get it to show only on rtl selected devices. (ar stands for Arab, if using a different rtl language you may find the code [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). Be-were that some devices support old-deprecated language codes so if it doesn't work try looking for older codes)